# Check if script has been redirected

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I have a `bash` script which must run differently if the output is being shown in the terminal, or if it is redirected to a file. It must do something like this (`myscript.sh`):

```
if [ redirected_to_terminal ] ; then
    flag="--color"
else
    flag="--no-color"
fi

grunt $flag
```

This would be called like this:

```
./myscript.sh
```

Or like this:

```
./myscript.sh > /tmp/log.txt
```

And the redirection of `stdout` would be detected in the script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `-t` option of bash:

```
 -t fd  True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.
```

And check like this:

```
if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
 # console is attached
else 
 # Redirected to somewhere
fi
```